# SaaS local data storage (and local runtime)

Tags: cloud, saas

In case I'm not in the right StackExchange forum, please advise me where to go with my question:

I'm working for a company, who has written software for handling sensitive data.
In order to prevent the software being copied along (software piracy), the decision has been made (a long time ago) to work with a licensing system.

This system is working fine, but it's a big burden, for my company as well as for the customers, hence I'm looking for other approaches.

One approach I've discovered is SaaS, but I see a huge drawback: Saas is working on the internet, which means that local data are uploaded onto the Cloud (the internet thus), which is making customers nervous (they want their precious data not to be uploaded into an environment they don't know and which they can't control).

While thinking about this, I see a resemblence between Java technology servlets and applets: a servlet runs on the server while an applet is run on the local PC.

Now I wonder if such a system also exists in SaaS: instead of having the software run, somewhere on the internet (like a servlet), is there a system where SaaS software is running on the local PC (like an applet)? The fact that the software runs on a local PC would avoid the need to upload sensitive data on the internet, which would be very interesting for our customers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with small amounts of client data (less than 4MB) you can look into HTML5 client storage. This is generally used to store temporary data and may or may not be right for you. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp.

Then again if you are not limited to SaaS architecture, you can consider an app model - you would still need to build separate apps for each platform you want to support. But you can easily store data locally on each machine.